# -bash: emacs: command not found (after updating mac to CATALINA)

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

After updating my mac to CATALINA, I have been dealing with some issues, and one of them is the fact that I can't open EMACS on the terminal:

> -bash: emacs: command not found

Anyone with the same issue, and knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: brew install emacs

Comment: in my case I already have an application on my mac called emacs but it cannot be found in the terminal...any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Catalina, Emacs is no longer provided in macOS. You'll have to download it from elsewhere, such as https://emacsforosx.com/ or https://aquamacs.org. There are other packages/distributions/ports listed at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS.

If you have one of those packages, you may have to re-install its command line tools/helpers.

Comment: Hi Nega, so I downloaded it from https://emacsforosx.com/, but how can I call it on my terminal? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `open -a Emacs` or `open /Applications/Emacs.app` will open Emacs. This works for any application properly installed on macOS. Also, read the first tip at https://emacsforosx.com/tips.

Comment: I mean how can I have emacs on my terminal, meaning no extra window, but open emacs with: emacs -nw [name of the file]

Comment: if you create the shell script, as suggested in the first tip at https://emacsforosx.com/tips, `scriptname -nw [name of the file]` would work just fine. Name the shell script `emacs` and you have what you want. Or you can just use the whole path `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw [name of the file]`.

Comment: @APORIL: You can just add `alias emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app -nw` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: in my case I already have an application on my mac called emacs but it cannot be found in the terminal...any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @CharlieParker make a symlink. create an alias. use a shell script. use `open -a emacs`. use `open /Applications/Emacs.app`. re-install the command-line tools/helpers that come with your particular Emacs package. if you need more help than this answer and it's comments provide, you should open a new question and provide as much detail as you can about your setup and what you're tying to do.

Answer (score 11):

If you can live with basic "emacs-like" editing, Catalina includes "mg" text editor. For more info:

```
man mg
```

Comment: quickest solution! "use what is already installed (that you may not have known about)".  mg is good enough for my needs.

Comment: in my case I already have an application on my mac called emacs but it cannot be found in the terminal...any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs can be installed on MacOS using Homebrew

```
$ brew cask install emacs
```

or Sudo

```
$ sudo port install emacs-app
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the brew in Mac, try this:

```
brew install emacs --no-quarantine --cask
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the classic command line version you can get it from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org):

```
sudo port install emacs
```

You can also get it view [HomeBrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/emacs).